# How to make eclipse svn checkout sources anonymously from public repository e.g. openam

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am using eclipse kepler on windows. I downloaded and installed the svn plugin. I need to check out sources for the open source openam project as detailed at [openam repository](http://openam.forgerock.org/source-repository.html)
. Essentially I need to do the equivalent of  svn checkout https://svn.forgerock.org/openam/trunk/ openam. When I do this via command line on ubuntu, it works without any problems. However, if I use eclipse svn plugin (or even tortoise svn on windows), it prompts me for username and password. I tried with anonymous (with and without a random password) but it denies access. I didn't find a way to configure eclipse with svn to checkout without password. Please provide suggestions on how to checkout sources then

Comment: I have the same issue. First time using SVN. Did you figure this out? Thanks.

Comment: Not the exact solution but while doing svn checkout I was getting same authentication popup.But ,since I just needed the code , I used svn export functionality to get code in my local machine. 
Hope this helps somebody facing the similar issue.